# Create JSON object from Multiline textbox windows phone

Tags: c#, json, dynamic, windows-phone-8

In my windows phone app, I'm in a need of creating a JSON object dynamically. i.e. I will know the property names only during run time. Also the property values can contain multiple lines.

Previously when I had to include multiple lines in a JSON object without any problem I used the following.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
ser.WriteObject(ms, obj);
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms))
{
     ms.Position = 0;
     input = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
return input;
```

This worked very fine. But in order to use I should've known the class before hand. Unfortunately it is not possible.

Can anyone help me with any work around ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

DataContractJsonSerializer does not support such things.
You should try, for instance, Json.net.